# Post to an external web service using BizTalk

Tags: http, post, parameters, biztalk

I need post to an external web service using BizTalk 2013R2, and I'm not sure how to add the parameters highlighted below.

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far.

I've created two way send/receive port using the WCF-WebHttp adapter. I set the endpoint to the sandbox url I was supplied: I set my HttpMethod and url mapping to

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping> <Operation Name = "WSPUORDER" Method="POST" Url="/WSPUORDER?provider=*****&amp;providerPassword=*****&amp;username=****&amp;password=*****&amp;postResponse={msg}"/> </BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

mapped the variable. error I get back is soap:versionMismatch.

Comment: Here is what I've tried so far. I've created two way send/receive port using the WCF-WebHttp adapter.  I set the endpoint to the sandbox url I was supplied: I set my HttpMethod and url mapping to 

<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
<Operation Name = "WSPUORDER" Method="POST" Url="/WSPUORDER?provider=*****&amp;providerPassword=*****&amp;username=****&amp;password=*****&amp;postResponse={msg}"/>
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>

mapped the variable.  

error I get back is soap:versionMismatch.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add additional information, rather than comments